# why does api gateway with http api using api mapping fail with 404?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a custom domain name in AWS API gateway. I am using the same domain for 2 separate API stages. One API stage is REST API, and the other HTTP API.

When I test out my setup, everything works for the REST API. However, the mapping path for HTTP API is not working and I get status-code = 404 Not Found, with 0kb body.

references used:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-mappings.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/rest-api-mappings.html

[image: api mapping configuration]

From my testing in postman, i get the following result when calling the custom domain.

```
 1. {{api.gateway.custom.domain.url}}/foobar - works
 2. {{api.gateway.custom.domain.url}}/this-no-work/foobar - 404
 3. {{api.gateway.custom.domain.url}}/this-works/foobar - works
```

does anyone know why (2) gives 404? api-gateway REST API with mapping works while api-gateway HTTP API will return 404 with 0kb body. Is there something I am missing?

note: the `(none)` path mapping has been added for a sanity check, and I was able to get the expected response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to answer from @gean-ribeiro, I was able to figure why my HTTP API was returning 404 Not Found.

Turns out it was not an issue with HTTP API. The error 404 Not Found with 0kb body was coming from the API integration sitting behind APIG. Specifically, it was a load balancer using rules based on HTTP path pattern.

By default, any unmatched path pattern will return 404 with text/plain body. `this-no-work` was a new HTTP API I added, and it did not have the necessary listener rules.

Once I added a new listener rule for `HTTP Path pattern is /this-no-work/*`, it worked as expected.[image: load balancer listener rules].

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

The problem is in the configuration of routers of your application.

When you configure one API mapping in AWS API Gateway, the configured path (this-no-work) is passed to your web application as a prefix of routes.

SO ... if you have one route like this:

> /api/foobar

you need configure one more route with the prefix point to the same action:

> /this-no-work/api/foobar

A good one is to make one global configuration to your web app.

You can note it enabling the cloudwatch logs of your API Gateway stage and looking into the cloudwatch logs the path property passed from API Gateway to the Web application.

Answer (score 0):

when default endpoin is created in my case it uses this pattern

> https://**{api_id}**.execute-api.{region}.amazonaws.com/

an answer might be: Disable the default endpoint for an HTTP API

more details here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-disable-default-endpoint.html