# API Gateway V2 Http API mapping returning "Not Found" when a "Path" is provided in the API mappings

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless, serverless-framework, api-gateway

> I've searched a lot of the "Not Found" errors on StackOverflow, along with other APIGW HTTP posts, and they don't match this exact scenario.

Tldr: Custom domain with APIGW V2 HTTP works when the "Path" is blank in the API mappings, but returns 404 "Not Found" when I add the exact path.

### Details

I'm using a custom domain (dev.myapp.com) configured in API Gateway. The DNS is setup correctly as you will see shortly.

Here is the API mapping I have setup:
[image]

The issue is:

- When I use the optional "Path", and invoke dev.myapp.com/oauth/callback/app the API Response returns 404 "Not Found"

  - I have logs enabled for the HttpApi and the logs don't show any events, so I'm guessing it is not matching to the mapping
- When I remove the optional "Path", then invoking dev.myapp.com/oauth/callback/app returns a successful 200

  - The logs show for the API that is mapped in this case

Been trying to solve this for a day and a half now. Tried many things like re-deploying, etcc.. I need to have multiple API mappings for this custom domain so using a single mapping with the Path field blank is not an option.

Other info:

- Custom domain config's "Endpoint type" is "Regional"
- The API is hooked up to invoke a lambda, which works properly when the "Path" is removed in the API mappings
- I'm using Serverless Framework to deploy the V2 API. Here is part of the serverless yml:

```yaml
app: myApp
service: ${self:app}-callback

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  region: us-east-1
  logs:
    httpApi: true # enable httpApi logs

functions:
  oauth-callback:
    handler: src/infra/oauth-app-callback-service/index.handler
    name: ${self:service}-oauth-callback-${sls:stage}
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /oauth/callback/app
          method: GET
```

I've tried re-deploying, smaller "path" such as only `oauth`, turning off "default endpoint", but none have worked. I've looked at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67189883/why-does-api-gateway-with-http-api-using-api-mapping-fail-with-404) but its a different issue which was with load balancer path rules which is not applicable here

What I expect is when using APIGW V2 HTTP with a custom domain and an API mappings with a "Path", the mapped API should be found and not return "Not Found"

Answer (score 0):

After much searching, I went to AWS's community and found [this post](https://repost.aws/questions/QUbrZO1k3MSr2JP2CoT_s0IQ/api-gateway-message-not-found).

> 1. Go to your API Gateway and select Route
> 2. Click Create
> 3. Leave the Any method as is and type in the path $default without a leading slash.
> 4. Click on Attach integration and select your web service endpoint

This worked and I no longer get the 404. Only issue is I have to do this manually and can't do this via Serverless Framework. I'll post a comment here if I figure it out.

Edit:
To set this automatically up with serverless framework, you need to use the `$default` path, which can only be done as such:

```
functions:
  oauth-callback:
    handler: src/infra/oauth-app-callback-service/index.handler
    name: ${self:service}-oauth-callback-${sls:stage}
    events:
      - httpApi: '*'
```

Now you're custom domain API mapping will work without having to deploy and then set the $default route for each API.